# Ajax call stops abrupt and goes to Http Post instead

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have a form, where throught templates the html is replaced when the user clicks a button and fills in parts of the form (I do it this way to guide the user in what he fills in first). the problem is at the end I do an ajax call to save all changes to the database, but instead of going to the succes function of the ajax call it goes to the httppost of my controller action and crashes the application.

here's my html code with the templates:

```
<h2>Nieuwe testrit</h2>

<p>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Terug naar lijst" 
 onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("index", "TestDrive")'" />
 </p>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
<div class="form-group" id="stepReloadDiv">
    @Html.Label("Auto", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="form-inline">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="selectCarVIN" value="Selecteer een auto." readonly="readonly" />
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-outline" value="Auto selecteren" onclick="SelectCar()" />
        </div>
        <br />
        <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="numberOfDays()" ; id="buttonNumberOfDays" disabled>Next <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
        @Html.Hidden("carId")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.carId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
}



@section Scripts {
<script src="~/Scripts/CustomTestDriveAddScript.js"></script>
<script>
    function SelectCar() {
        var w = $(window).width() - 700;
        var h = $(window).height() - 100;
        $('#cboxLoadingGraphic').show();
        $.colorbox({
            href: '@Url.Action("selectcarfortestdrive","car")',
            iframe: true,
            fastIframe: false,
            transition: 'elastic',
            innerWidth: w,
            innerHeight: h,
            scrolling: true
        });
    }

function SelectCustomer() {
    var w = $(window).width() - 100;
    var h = $(window).height() - 100;
    $('#cboxLoadingGraphic').show();
    $.colorbox({
        href: '@Url.Action("SelectCustomerForTestDrive","customer")',
        iframe: true,
        fastIframe: false,
        transition: 'elastic',
        innerWidth: w,
        innerHeight: h,
        scrolling: true
    });
}

</script>

<script id="lengthQuestionTemplate" type="text/template">
    <div class="col-md-10  col-md-offset-2">
        <h4>Gaat deze testrit over meer dan 1 uur/meerdere dagen?</h4>
        <div class="form-inline">
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-outline" onclick='nextStepStartDateMultipleDays();'>Ja <i class="fas fa-check-circle" style="color:green"></i></button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-outline" onclick='nextStepStartDateOneDay();'>Nee <i class="fas fa-times-circle" style="color:#af1515"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>

<script id="endDateTemplate" type="text/template">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Einddatum", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.endDate, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "endDate", @type = "date", @onchange = "endDateChanged();" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.endDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Eindtijd", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.endBlockId, new SelectList("", "id", "endTime"), new { @class = "form-control", @id = "endTimeDropdown", @onchange = "endTimeChanged();" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.endBlockId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <span id="errorMsg"></span>
            <button class="btn btn-success col-md-offset-2" onclick="nextStepChooseEndDate('endDate', 'endTimeDropdown')" ; id="buttonChooseEndDate" disabled>Next <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></button> 
        </div>      
    </div>
</script>

<script id="startDateTemplate" type="text/template">
    @Html.Label("Startdatum", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="form-inline">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.startDate, new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "startDateChangedSingle();", @type = "date" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.startDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <br />
        <span id="errorMsg"></span>
        <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="nextStepChooseStartDate('startDate');" ; id="buttonTimeSingle" disabled>Next <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
    </div>
</script>

<script id="startDateTemplateMultipe" type="text/template">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Startdatum", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.startDate, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @class = "form-control", @type = "date", @id = "startDate", @onchange = "startDateChangedMultiple();" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.startDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Starttijd", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.startBlockId, new SelectList("", "id", "startTime"), new { @class = "form-control", @id = "startTimeDropdown" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.startBlockId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <span id="errorMsg"></span>
            <button class="btn btn-success col-md-offset-2" onclick="nextStepChooseStartDateMultiple('startDate', 'startTimeDropdown');" ; id="buttonStartMultiple" disabled>Next <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
<script id="choseTimeSingle" type="text/template">
    @Html.Label("Starttijd", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="form-inline">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.startBlockId, new SelectList("", "id", "time"), new { @class = "form-control", @id = "timeDropdown", @onchange = "startTimeChangedSingle();" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.startBlockId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <br />
        <span id="errorMsg"></span>
        <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="nextStepChooseTime('timeDropdown');" ; id="buttonTimeSingle">Next <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
    </div>
</script>

<script id="choseLicenceplate" type="text/template">
    @Html.Label("Nummerplaat", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="form-inline">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.licenceplateId, new SelectList("", "id", "licenceplate1"), new { @class = "form-control", @id = "licensePlateDropdown" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.licenceplateId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <br />
        <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="nextStepChooseLicenceplate('licensePlateDropdown');" ; id="buttonTimeSingle">Next <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
    </div>
</script>

<script id="choseCustomer" type="text/template">
    @Html.Label("Klant", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="form-inline">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="selectCustomerId" value="Selecteer een klant." readonly="readonly" />
            @Html.Hidden("customerId")
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-outline" value="Klant selecteren" onclick="SelectCustomer()" />
        </div>
        <br />
        <button class="btn btn-success" id="buttonSelectCustomer" onclick="nextStepChooseCustomer('customerId');" disabled>Next <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
    </div>
</script>

<script id="choseType" type="text/template">
    @Html.Label("Type uitlening", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="form-inline">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.customerId, new SelectList(ViewBag.testdriveTypes, "id", "name"), new { @class = "form-control", @id = "testDriveTypeDropDown" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.testDriveTypeId, "", 
 new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <br/>
        <button class="btn btn-success" 
onclick="nextStepFinishEdit('testDriveTypeDropDown');">Aanmaken</button>
    </div>  
</script>

<script id="Done" type="text/template">
    <div class="col-md-10  col-md-offset-2">
            <h4>Uw testrit is succesvol toegevoegd.</h4>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Naar testrit" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</script>
 }
```

with my ajac call being:

```
function nextStepFinishEdit(valueId) {
var value = document.getElementById(valueId).value;
testDriveTypeId = value;
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/NewTestDrives/fundallocation",
    data: {
        "licenseplateId": licencePlateId,
        "carId": carId,
        "startDate": startDate,
        "endDate": endDate,
        "customerId": customerId,
        "testDriveTypeId": testDriveTypeId,
        "startBlockId": startBlockId,
        "endBlockId": endBlockId
    },
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        var inner = document.getElementById('stepReloadDiv');
        inner.innerHTML = document.getElementById('Done').innerHTML;
    }
});
}
```

the code where the call is going to:

```
public async Task FundAllocation(int licenseplateId, int carId, string startDate, string endDate, int customerId, int testDriveTypeId, int startBlockId, int endBlockId)
    {
        NewTestDriveModel testDriveModel = new NewTestDriveModel
        {
            carId = carId,
            customerId = customerId,
            endBlockId = endBlockId,
            endDate = endDate,
            licenseplateId = licenseplateId,
            startBlockId = startBlockId,
            startDate = startDate,
            testDriveTypeId = testDriveTypeId
        };

        var testDrives = testDriveService.GetTestDrivesByDay(Convert.ToDateTime(testDriveModel.startDate));
        var customer = customerService.GetCustomerById(testDriveModel.customerId);
        var usedLicensplates = new List<int>();

        foreach (var drive in testDrives)
        {
            if (drive.startBlockId == testDriveModel.startBlockId)
            {
                usedLicensplates.Add(drive.licenceplateId);
            }

            if (drive.carId == testDriveModel.carId && drive.startBlockId == testDriveModel.startBlockId)
            {
                return;
            }
        }

            TestDrive testDrive = new TestDrive
            {
                carId = testDriveModel.carId,
                customerId = testDriveModel.customerId,
                endBlockId = testDriveModel.endBlockId,
                endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(testDriveModel.endDate),
                licenceplateId = testDriveModel.licenseplateId,
                startBlockId = testDriveModel.startBlockId,
                startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(testDriveModel.startDate),
                testDriveTypeId = testDriveModel.testDriveTypeId
            };

            testDriveId = testDriveService.AddTestDrive(testDrive);
            Session["testDriveId"] = testDriveId;

        CalendarHelper calendarHelper = new CalendarHelper();

        CarService carService = new CarService();
        string licenceplate = licenseplateService.GetLicenceplateById(testDriveModel.licenseplateId).licenceplate1;

        Car car = carService.GetCarById(testDriveModel.carId);

        CarModel newCarModel = new CarModel
        {
            Series = car.series,
            Name = car.name,
            VINNumber = car.VINNumber,
        };

        CalendarEventModel model = new CalendarEventModel()
        {
            CustomerFirstname = customer.firstname,
            CustomerLastname = customer.name,
            TestDrive = testDriveModel,
            Car = newCarModel,
            Licenceplate = licenceplate,
            TestDriveId = testDriveId
        };

        MailHelper mailHelper = new MailHelper();

        TimeBlock startBlock = timeBlockService.GetTimeBlockById(testDriveModel.startBlockId);
        TimeBlock endBlock = timeBlockService.GetTimeBlockById(testDriveModel.endBlockId);

        CustomerReservationConfirmationMailModel mailModel = new CustomerReservationConfirmationMailModel()
        {
            CarSerie = car.series,
            CarName = car.name,
            Motor = car.motor,
            Model = car.modelType,
            StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(testDriveModel.startDate).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
            EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(testDriveModel.endDate).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
            StartHour = startBlock.startTime,
            EndHour = endBlock.endTime,
            Customer = customer,
            Licenceplate = licenceplate
        };

        await mailHelper.SendCustomerReservationConfirmationMail(mailModel);

        await calendarHelper.AddEventAsync(model);
    }
```

And my controller actions:

```
        public ActionResult Add()
    {
        ViewBag.Customer = customerService.All();
        ViewBag.testdriveTypes = testDriveTypeService.GetAll();
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(string s)
    {
        var testDriveId = Session["testDriveId"];
        return RedirectToAction("details", new { id = testDriveId });
    }
```

so the ajax call fires, and the database is being update but the succes function where i replace the html is never called, instead it directly goes to my Http post, how can I prevent this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default your button that calls the nextStepFinishEdit function will have a type of 'submit'. Since you have this inside of your @html.BeginForm() it will submit that form. This is what is causing your POST request to fire. Just add type='button' like:

```
     <button class="btn btn-success" type='button'
onclick="nextStepFinishEdit('testDriveTypeDropDown');">Aanmaken</button>
```